# Check pandas DataFrame values with pydantic

Tags: python, pandas, pydantic

I have DataFrame, and would like to add a new column to it with rows filled by JSONs, that consists of values from other columns. like that:

| id | a_field | b_field | json |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | "abc" | {"num":1, "name":"abc"} |

so values from row get to flat structure but with different names.

And I'd like to create that json using pydantic.
And to check such frames with pydantic if i get it from elsewhere.
What's the best way to do it?

Comment: To complete my answer I would like to know what you mean by " And to check such frames with pydantic if i get it from elsewhere".

Comment: if i get a dataframe, that already has a json column - i would like to validate it using pydantic module

Comment: @DenisKa if there's a validation error would your write `None` on that row or how would you handle it ?

Comment: @MiguelTrejo write None or even raise an error

Answer (score 2):

If I get the question right, you can parse it something like this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
import json

class JSON(BaseModel):
    num: int
    name: str
    

obj = JSON(**json.loads('{"num":1, "name":"abc"}'))
assert obj.json() == '{"num": 1, "name": "abc"}'
```